# Let $(X, d_1)$ be a metric space, and let $d_2(x,y)=\frac{d_1(x,y)}{1+d_1(x,y)}$, show that $d_1$ and $d_2$ give the same open sets

Tags: real-analysis

I'm stuck on this problem. I need to show basically a set is an open set with respect to $d_1$ if and only if it is an open set with respect to $d_2$. Thanks.

Comment: Show the open balls are the same.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more?

Answer (score 1):

Verify that $B_1(x,r)$ contains $B_2(x,s)$ if $s=\frac r {1+r}$ and $B_2(x,r)$ contains $B_1(x,s)$ if $s=\frac r {1-r}$ provded r<1. Can you handle the case $r\geq 1$?